# How to use two links to same element, one as main link and the other one as a fail-safe in HTML?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible for me to include two **href** into the same tag. I don't want them to open simultaneously or anything... I just want it to open the first link first, if the source is **not available**, I want it to open the second link. Is it possible to get this result using only **HTML**?

Comment: I am aware of hacks for opening 2 links with in the same tag, but I never heard of such fallback mechanism with a second link. How would that work? It is possible with an image, yes.

Comment: For an image, in this case I use it as a fallback for browsers that don't support webp image format (which are becoming less and less thankfully) : `<img alt="xx" src="/images/xx.webp" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/images/xx.jpg'">`